# Load Pidgin from the command line and join an IRC channel

Tags: command-line, pidgin

I would like to be able to add a function to my .bashrc or .profile file in Ubuntu 13.04 that loads Pidgin and automatically joins a given IRC channel. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea where to put it, but if you put somewhere sensible:

```
pidgin --login=NAME
```

replacing `NAME` with your IRC login (has to be above the list of any others with the same name), that should do the trick.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you believe editing a ~/.profile is bad?

Comment: No reason sorry, corrected